# How to get config params in another module in flask python?

Tags: python, flask, config

In my main.py have the below code:

```
app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
```

In another module I used `import main` and then used `main.app.config['KEY']` to get a parameter, but Python interpreter says that it couldn't load the module in `main.py` because of the import part. How can I access config parameters in another module in `Flask`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access config values in Flask from other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017527/access-config-values-in-flask-from-other-files)

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is not really clear but by what I can get, import your configuration object and just pass it to app.config.from_object():

```
from flask import Flask
from <path_to_config_module>.config import DevelopmentConfig

app = Flask('Project')
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

if your your config module is in the same directory where your application module is, you can just use :

```
from .config import DevelopmentConfig
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to put app initialization in another file (e.g: myapp_init_file.py) in the root:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Change this on production environment to: config.ProductionConfig
app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
```

Now to access config parameters I just need to import this module in different files:

```
from myapp_init_file import app
```

Now I have access to my config parameters as below:

```
app.config['url']
```

The problem was that I had an import loop an could not run my python app. With this solution everything works like a charm. ;-)