# Access config values in Flask from other files

Tags: python, flask

I have the following app structure:

```
manage.py
myapp/
  __init__.py
  config.py
  views/
    __init__.py
    login.py
    ...
```

In `myapp/__init__.py` I have a function `create_app()` which returns the Flask app instance. The config values are also stated in `create_app()` too. I would like to be able to access these values in other files such as `login.py`. I've tried:

```
from myapp import create_app as app
print app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```

However I receive an error stating `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'config'`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use `from flask import current_app`. You define `SECRET_KEY` in `settings.py`.

`print current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']`

Comment: I have no `settings.py` file and I would rather set all the config values in `config.py` instead.

Comment: I tried the current_app method and receive this: `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`

Comment: Make sure you initialize the config file with `app.config.from_object('myapp.config')` as shown in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/

Comment: To avoid `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.` make sure that you are calling `current_app` within the context of a request. See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context)

Comment: When I check the address of app in main python file and current_app in sub file, the values are different. Doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, for the next person that needs this. I had a similar setup from the tutorials.

```
from myapp import create_app

app = create_app()
print app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```

Comment: This works if using the application factory

Answer (score 0):

**Two scenerios:**

**1.** Your code is within app scope:

Add this to top of your file
`from flask import current_app`

To access variables saved to your app config: `current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']` **or** `current_app.config.get('SECRET_KEY')`

Make sure you called `app.config.from_object(config)` in your *app* or _*init*_ py file or initialize your app.config in a different manner.

**2.** Your code is outside app scope or it is being compiled before app is initialized. There are a few options.

**a.** Import your secret key from your environment.

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY", "defaultSecret")
```

**b.** Import your secret key from a local file:

```
from local import config

SECRET_KEY = config.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

Where local is the file that contains your configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

Create the app with app context and init your db and other dependencies

```
def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="assets")
cfg = import_string(environ.get('PROFILE'))()
app.config.from_object(cfg)

with app.app_context():
   init_db()
```

then you can use

```
from flask import current_app

def init_db(self):
  mongo_client = MongoClient(current_app.config['DATABASE_URI'])
```